# How to store drop down selected text in hidden field using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am new in Jquery and google artical not help me out. I know it will be very easy. Any way As i can able to store drop down selected value in hidden filed, simmilarly i want to store selected Item in another hidden filed But unable to do same.
Can any one help me ?

**storing drop down Value working perfectly**

```
$('#ddlLocation').change(function (e) {
                $('#hdnvalue').val(this.value);
            });
```

`hdnvalue` is my hidden filed ID for storing value

**storing selected Text not working**:

```
 $('#ddlLocation').change(function (e) {
                $('#hdnvalue').val(this.value);
                $('#hdntext').val($("#ddlLocation option:selected").text()); 
            });
```

`hdntext` is my another hidden filed ID for storing text

Comment: your code should work but can you share the relevant HTML in the post? also use code snippet to reproduce it

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar sure please check my updated code

Comment: @saf can you please see the console if there is any error?

Comment: @JamshaidKamran there is no error on console

Comment: Then it means your events are not being bound to your control

Comment: its working thanx

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have a simple fix for this.

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
   
   $("#example").on("change",function(){
      $this = $("#example option:selected");
       
        $("#storeValue").val($this.val());
        $("#storeText").val($this.text());
       

   });
 </script>
```

```html
 <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
   
 </head>
 

 <select id="example">
   <option value="one">one-text</option>
   <option value="two">two-text</option>
   <option value="three">three-text</option>
   <option value="four">four-text</option>
 </select>

 <input type="hidden" id="storeValue">
 <input type="hidden" id="storeText">
```

```js
   $("#example").on("change",function(){
      $this = $("#example option:selected");
       
        $("#storeValue").val($this.val());
        $("#storeText").val($this.text());
       

   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="example">
   <option value="one">one-text</option>
   <option value="two">two-text</option>
   <option value="three">three-text</option>
   <option value="four">four-text</option>
 </select>

 <input type="hidden" id="storeValue">
 <input type="hidden" id="storeText">
```

Comment: I replace my code as suggested $("#storeText").val($this.text()); showing error this.text is not a function

Comment: hello,
you have to put like this  $this = $("#storeText option:selected");

Comment: and also please check your jquery version

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 add this to top of your web page

Comment: or you can also use  $this = $(this).find("option:selected"); likethis Hope your problem now solved

Answer (score 0):

From the comments and the description, I am guessing the ID of the `DropDownList` `ddlLocation` is being modified and hence you are not being able to bind any jquery event with it. I recommend binding the `DropDownList` like this:

```
$('#<%= ddlLocation.ClientID %>').change(function (e) {
    $('#<%= hdnvalue.ClientID %>').val($(this).val());
    // DoStuff
});
```